# EF 4.1, How to initialize data when you need images

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

xxI need to initialize some data on my model, but as you can see in the below code, I have a field for ProductImage.

If the images are on a local path, is there anyway to seed the database with images?
Please see the Applicants class.

```
  public class HRContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicantImage> ApplicantImages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicantPosition> ApplicantsPositions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationPositionHistory> ApplicationsPositionHistory { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Position>().ToTable("Position");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>().ToTable("Applicant");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicantPosition>().ToTable("ApplicantPosition");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationPositionHistory>().ToTable("ApplicationsPositionHistory");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Position>().Property(c => c.name).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>().Property(c => c.name).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicantPosition>().Property(c => c.appliedDate).IsRequired();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class HRContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<HRContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(HRContext context)
        {
            Position netdeveloper = new Position() { name = ".net developer", yearsExperienceRequired = 5 };
            Position javadeveloper = new Position() { name = "java developer", yearsExperienceRequired = 5 };

            Applicant luis = new Applicant()
            {
                name = "Luis",
                skypeuser = "le.xx",
                telephone = "345353453",

            };

            Applicant john = new Applicant()
            {
                name = "John",
                skypeuser = "jo.valencia",
                telephone = "3435343543"
            };


            ApplicantPosition appicantposition = new ApplicantPosition()
            {
                Applicant =luis, Position = netdeveloper, appliedDate=DateTime.Today,Status=Status.Applied
            };

            context.Positions.Add(netdeveloper);
            context.Positions.Add(javadeveloper);
            context.Applicants.Add(luis);
            context.Applicants.Add(john);
            context.ApplicantsPositions.Add(appicantposition);


        }

    }

    public class Position
    {
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength=3)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int yearsExperienceRequired { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicantPosition> applicantPosition { get; set; }
    }

    public class Applicant
    {
        public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        public string skypeuser { get; set; }
        public ApplicantImage photo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicantPosition> applicantPosition { get; set; }

    }

    public class ApplicantPosition
    {
        public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
        public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
        public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
        public DateTime appliedDate { get; set; }
        public int StatusValue { get; set; }

        public Status Status
        {
            get { return (Status)StatusValue; }
            set { StatusValue = (int)value; }
        }

        //[NotMapped]
        //public int numberOfApplicantsApplied
        //{
        //    get
        //    {
        //        int query =
        //             (from ap in Position
        //              where ap.Status == (int)Status.Applied
        //              select ap
        //                  ).Count();
        //        return query;
        //    }
        //}
    }




    public class ApplicantImage
    {
        public int ApplicantId { get; private set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }    
    }



    public class ApplicationPositionHistory
    {
        public ApplicantPosition applicantPosition { get; set; }
        public Status oldStatus { get; set; }
        public Status newStatus { get; set; }
        [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string comments { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Status
    {
        Applied,
        AcceptedByHR,
        AcceptedByTechnicalDepartment,
        InterviewedByHR,
        InterviewedByTechnicalDepartment,
        InterviewedByGeneralManager,
        AcceptedByGeneralManager,
        NotAccepted
    }
```

Comment: was my answer helpful or is it still not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just read the image and put it in the byte array?

```
ApplicantImage jonhImage = new ApplicantImage()
  {
      Image = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
  };

Applicant john = new Applicant()
{
  name = "John",
  skypeuser = "jo.valencia",
  telephone = "3435343543"
  photo = jonhImage
};
...
context.ApplicantImages.Add(jonhImage);
```

What exception do you get?